# Finding the dimension of subspace $S=\{ \left[\begin{smallmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\\ \end{smallmatrix}\right] \mid c = a + b, d=a \}.$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let the subspace $S$ from $M_{2\times2}$: $$S=\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}
> a & b\\
> c & d\\
> \end{bmatrix} \mid c = a + b\textrm{ and }d=a \right\}.$$ What is the dimension of $S$?

According to the answer key, $\dim (S)=2$. Why is it not $\dim(S)=2\times2=4$? What am I missing?

Comment: The dimension of $M_{2\times 2}$ is equal to $2\times 2=4$, but $S$ is a smaller subspace of $M_{2\times 2}$, so the dimension is less.

Comment: Since $c, d$ can both be described in terms of $a,b$ two parameters define all of the matrices in S.  S is a subspace of $M_{2\times 2}, M_{2\times 2}$ is indeed a 4 dimensional vector space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have determined $a$ and $b$, you already know what $c$ and $d$ should be. It's imposed on you. Hence, the dimension of the subspace, which can be thought of as the number of independent variables in this case, is $2$. You can also prove this rigorously by showing that

$$B=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\1 & 1\\\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\
1 & 0\\\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$

is a basis for this subspace, *i.e.* $S$ is spanned by those two matrices and they are linearly independent.

Comment: Just to clarify: if the number of independent variables were $3$, then $dim(S)=3$?

Comment: @MauricioMendes  Yes. You can say so. For example, if $d$ didn't need to be equal to $a$ and it could be arbitrary, the dimension of $S$ would've been $3$ then.

Comment: @CameronBuie Yeah. I changed this like 2 seconds before you write this comment. xD My notation was bad because I was using $S$ both for the set itself and its span and I decided to change my notation completely.

Comment: +1: Glad you figured out the formatting. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The subspace $S$ consist of matrices of the form
$
\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b \\
 a+b& a \\
\end{pmatrix}
$. Every such matrix can be written as a linear combination
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b \\
 a+b& a \\
\end{pmatrix}=
a\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}+
b\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
If you also check that the matrices
$\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ are linearly independent, you get that this is a basis for $S$.

Answer (score 0):

$S$ is $2$ dimensional.   $M_{2×2}\cong\mathbb F^4$, where $\mathbb F$ is the field you are working over.

A basis for $S$ is $\{\begin {pmatrix} 1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\2&1\end{pmatrix}\}$.